# MailApp sending gmail account anonymous account

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that sends an email to the person who submitted a form to me.  However, I would like to send the email from an "anonymous" account so the confirmation email doesn't come from my account.  Is there a way to send it from a different account so it doesn't look like I am manually generating all these emails.  Thanks!

My script is something like the following:

```
  if (user = email) {
  GmailApp.sendEmail(user, subject, message);
  }
```

Where 'user' is the google account of the person submitting and 'email' is the email address the person submitting wishes to have the confirmation sent to.

Again, is there a way to make the `GmailApp.sendEmail(from:'Anonymous')` ???

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't answer fully that it can be anonymous.  You could author the app with a "dummy" account to obscure your email address, but if you're on a business or education account that won't really work.  Also, you can put a little bit of smoke to distract the recipient by giving the email an "alias" name.

```
MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail,
  "Help Desk Ticket",
  "Thanks for submitting your issue. \n\nWe'll start " +
  "working on it as soon as possible. \n\nHelp Desk",
  {name:"Help Desk"});
}​
```

The most important part of that is the element in the last line {name:"Help Desk}.  This makes your email "name" Help Desk, but you can still see the sending email address if you mouse over it (which is why I recommended a "dummy" email address in the beginning).

You can see the context of the script in this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/helpdesk_tutorial

Here is an example of how I used the same thing in a script:

```
    function mailCheatSheet(copyId,userEmail,mrNumber){
      var copyId = copyId;
      var userEmail = userEmail;
      var mrNum = mrNumber;
      // Convert temporary document to PDF by using the getAs blob conversion
      var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf"); 
      // Attach PDF and send the email
      var subject = "SA Funding request by: "+userEmail;
      var body = userEmail +" has submitted a SA Funding Inquiry for " +mrNumber +", which is attached to this email.  \n"
           +"Please ensure there are no errors before printing.  \n"
           +"If there are errors, please notify: xyz@abc.com.  \n\n";
      MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, body, {name: 'SA Worksheet Helperbot', htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf}); 
      // Delete temp file
      DocsList.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
    }
```

If you just want to make it look like you're not sitting around all day typing out email responses to things (I'd assume so your boss thinks you're doing something useful), then you could add the alias name to your GmailApp method AND add a disclaimer line at the bottom of the email body like this:

```
    var body = userEmail +" has submitted a SA Funding Inquiry for " +mrNumber +", which is attached to this email.  \n"
        +"Please ensure there are no errors before printing."
        +"\n\nThis email was automatically authored by Form Helperbot.  If there is an error, please report it to: dummyEmail@xyz.com"    
    MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, body,{name: 'Form Helperbot',htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send from an anonymous account only because you don't want to receive the replies, it might be a better idea to specify a dummy reply-to address in your email notifications.

```
  MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, body, {name: 'SA Worksheet Helperbot', htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf, replyTo: donotreply@example.com});
```